# How to Advance Barbaric Tribes

Tags: intelligence, education, tribes

In a world full of barbaric tribes, there lives a small gathering of advanced sages. Their hearts are full of knowledge and benevolence for all living beings. They can advance human being to the highest level of intelligence and transform this ugly planet into a world of advanced civilizations.

The barbarians are full of bad qualities. They kill, rape, steal, eat flesh, constantly argue over lowly world matters. They suffer from ignorance, diseases and war.

Few tribes knows about the legends of wise men who live in the North. How can barbarians gather up and decide to visit the sages to advance and become intelligent kings. How can they successfully build an advanced civilization and live in peace and happiness?

---

Due to vastness of the question, let's assume the tribes along with their representatives have already found a way to visit the sages and are already there. Now this puts you in the position of the sage... Is anyone a sage here? Now we need to talk abut all kind of knowledges of building civilizations, and all about kinghood...

What would you teach to barbarians? What do you think will work for uplifting barbarians into more advanced state of consciousness? Please explain how new learned knowledge reflects on their existence on planet? For example, if you teach them hygiene. How would they benefit? Even though I haven defined the barbaric tribe, feel free to provide your own original examples and solutions.

Comment: I'm not at all certain what is the intended meaning of "advanced sages". What do those sages *do*, what do they *have* which is desirable for the barbarians who don't do and don't have it? In fact, I'm not convinced that I fully understand why "eating flesh" is a "bad quality" of the same rank as killing, raping and stealing. (And what exactly does "rape" mean in a barbarian world? It is highly dependend on the historical context.) As for "arguing about lowly mundane matters", I would say that this is rather crucial for social advancement: after all, this "lowly world" is where we all live.

Comment: For example, in the real history the barbarians invaded the Roman Empire because the empire had more and better food (because agriculture), had better clothes, had more gold and silver, had glassware, had very much better houses etc. In the process, the barbarians learned how exactly the Romans did it, and tried to imitate the Roman way of life; they failed, but it still was a big step up from their former level. Eventually, the remnants of the former civilization percolated in the society, and the barbarians understood the value of the rule of law and of planning and so on, and here we are.

Comment: @AlexP, so you are a barbarian! Well, sages know everything about human life. As I have said, only a handful of tribes knows about the sages and is advanced enough to start planning to visit them and take instructions. Other tribes are so low that they don't even like the idea of an intelligent human being.

Comment: @Marino "and is advanced enough to start planning to visit them and take instructions." Pardon me if I don't believe for a moment the barbarians intend to take _instructions_ from the sages.

Comment: @Marino I encourage you to read about Christian missionary efforts throughout history, because they did exactly what you’re asking across four continents and did it with impressive degrees of success

Comment: @NixonCranium, thanks. The monks must have been very learned men.

Comment: @Marino Indeed they were the most learned men in all Europe

Comment: through the rumble of scientific triumph ? and tell them kill, rape, steal, eat flesh, constantly argue over lowly world matters is bad, done a lot especially by religious figure or through story telling because who dont want to hear a good night story, or even better to appointing this sage as the ruler of the barbarian tribe.

Comment: Welcome, Marino. This is a huge, open-ended question. It's dependent on geography, culture, access to technology, resources, and population, so I'm going to vote to close as "needs details or clarity." Even if such details were provided, there are 3 separate questions here: 1) how do they find out about the sages, 2) how do they travel to them, and 3) how do they build a civ. Question #3 itself is exceedingly broad, let alone all 3, so others will VTC as "needs more focus." Could you edit the question to provide relevant details and narrow your scope?

Comment: @Zxyrra, the question is indeed broad. I could focus on the last part: transforming barbarians into kings and building a civilization. Thank you clarifying thing out.

Answer (score 0):

**Christian Missionaries Did This Multiple Times in Europe**

Your prompt of sagacious men going to ultra violent barbarians and convincing them to adopt a new set of social norms is exactly what hundreds of Christian missionaries did successfully throughout late antiquity and the early medieval period.

Things like endemic raiding, human sacrifice, cannibalism  infanticide and polygyny were all stamped out or marginalized  by Christian missionaries with surprising success.

The Church introduced a new ethical system and brought Greco-Roman philosophy far beyond the reach of the Roman Empire.

[Ulfilas](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Ulfilas) Introduced literacy to the Goths through Christianity

[St Cyril and St Methodius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saints_Cyril_and_Methodius) Created the Cyrillic Script in their efforts at Christianizing the Slavs, and brought these peoples into the Byzantine sphere of influence.

[The Magyars](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3160418) were turned from nomadic raiders to an integral European power through the power of the Church.

[The Vikings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianization_of_Scandinavia) stopped being extremely destructive raiders and integrated economically into  mainland Europe due to being Christianized and therefore no longer following an insanely violent religion that praised ya know raiding and invading.

Early medieval kings constantly relied on Monks and Bishops for all matters of advice spiritual and temporal.

Monasteries were the centers of knowledge and preserved basically all of the written material in the western world at the time.

So all your sages have to do is convince the barbarians that they’re completely wrong about how the universe works and that the sages know the true nature of the world and human destiny through God’s inerrant Word. Good luck

Comment: I got to highly disagree with this seeing the Northern tribes were far from barbarians the Christians made them out to be. And one of their most effective ways of conversion was by the sword, killing everybody who did not convert. Another was the introduction of being forgiven for their sins... Also a minor % of the vikings were raiders who did this  ..most were just normal farmers... and take a look at the barbarism Christianity brought with it...

Comment: @A.bakker The Christians had no need to make the Norse out to be barbarians, the constant aggression of the Norse as recorded in their own stories and in numerous attestations is proof enough. If the Norse weren’t barbarians literally no one else in human history was.

Comment: @A.bakker The prompt states “ They kill, rape, steal, eat flesh, constantly argue over lowly world matters. They suffer from ignorance, diseases and war.” Only one of these things does not apply to the Norse. The amount of violent conversion done by Christians and Muslims historically is dramatically overstated in pop history

Comment: They mainly relied on peaceful trading and farming... The raiders were only a minor %, it was seasonal and it diminished heavily even before Christians came...And killing women and children because they don't believe in your god...how is that not barbaric?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_and_violence

Comment: @A.bakker lmao, look up Norse paganism and violence. You’re not going to win here

Comment: Id one barbarian tribe converts a other...they suddenly stop being barbarians?  " They kill, rape, steal, eat flesh, constantly argue over lowly world matters" describes Christians as much ad Norse pagans, Muslims or any other tribe of people in the world.

Comment: @A.Bakker “ They mainly relied on peaceful trading and farming... The raiders were only a minor %, it was seasonal and it diminished heavily even before Christians came...” They conquered most of England and Ireland dude. They were extorting Francia and the HRE through force. Their raids were so frequent that they lead to the development of castles and fortifications in Western Europe. “ And killing women and children because they don't believe in your god...” You do realize that the Norse killed people for their religion right? They literally sacrificed humans and held warfare sacred

Comment: @A.bakker “ Id one barbarian tribe converts a other...they suddenly stop being barbarians? " They kill, rape, steal, eat flesh, constantly argue over lowly world matters" describes Christians as much ad Norse pagans, Muslims or any other tribe of people in the world.” Ah, you pulled out the “everyone sucks card” a sure sign of defeat in online arguments. Thanks for the quick ending

Comment: Not saying they are saints, i am saying that the christian conversion didn't improve anything. They just replaces one "barbaric" way of life with a other one. And your answer make it seem it was done " peacefully"  while it is the farthest from the truth.

Comment: The "argument"  is that your answer isn't correct because they don't meet the criteria of " Their hearts are full of knowledge and benevolence for all living beings."  the OP had.

Comment: @A.bakker “ Not saying they are saints, i am saying that the christian conversion didn't improve anything.” Tell that to the people of Great Britain and France in the 9th century. Their lives absolutely improved with Viking raids ceasing and beneficial trade replacing it. Tell that to the Scandinavians who now had stable kingdoms Integrating into European trade. Tell that to people that didn’t get their throats slit and dumped in a bog for Freya

Comment: @A.bakker  “And your answer make it seem it was done " peacefully" while it is the farthest from the truth.” You do realize that the Norse weren’t all converted at sword point right? It was Norse pagan vs Norse Christian factions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105023/discussion-between-nixoncranium-and-a-bakker).

Comment: Without engaging with the highly debatable idea of Christian missionaries as "advanced sages", I want only to clarify that the Cyrillic alphabet was **not** invented by Constantine of Thessalonica (= St. Cyril). He did indeed invent an alphabet suitable for writing late Common Slavic or Old Church Slavonic (practically the same thing), namely the [Glagolitic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glagolitic_script). The isomorphic (but very very much easier on the eyes) [Cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Cyrillic_alphabet) was created later, in the First Bulgarian Empire.

Comment: I'm late to the party but this is actually a really good answer! Two things to add: 1. Barbarian means "foreigner" it picked up the negative connotation from people in cities (Athens/Rome/etc.) talking down to tribal outsiders. Very similar to people from NYC bad mouthing rednecks. 2. The core of the question has to do with converting hostile groups to your way of thinking (maybe the sages are actually the bad guys, judgement call isn't needed here). Religious evangelism is a great model for this. Applies to Christianity, Islam, Buddhism, and Confucianism - all of them spread like wildfire.

Answer (score 0):

**Eugenics.**

As an advanced sage myself, I know that my refined and civilization-improving qualities arise from my superior ancestry and gene pool.  Yes, a lucky accident in the distant past on the part of one of my esteemed ancestors, but I (and my sage brothers-in-sageliness) are the enlightened recipients of this refined and superior genetic heritage.  We are ready to share.

Rather than persuade the benighted barbarians of the (many) errors of their ways, we sages only need to persuade them of our genetic superiority, and as a consequence the need for us to be the fathers of all of their babies.  Barbarian women as depicted by Frank Frazetta will be brought to sage central to reside with us for a while, where with our gentle attentions we will help them conceive half-sage babies.  These babies will grow up with some of our sage and enlightened birthrights.  Over time, the barbarians will eugenically become more sagely, and the world a better place.  Barbarian males will concentrate their procreative energies in avenues other than their women, such as their horses, which is probably what they are up to anyway because barbarity and flesh eating.

I weep a self-sacrificatory tear - it will be a hard burden to shoulder for us monastic sages, who are also woefully out of practice in the business of conceiving half-sage or any other sort of baby given that we are all dudes up here in sage central.  But it is a burden we are willing to shoulder for the goodness of the world.  And soon, ok?